# Test the security of my Linux setup

Tags: malware, linux

I have a Ubuntu installation running in VirtualBox. I have made a few modifications to it (some kernel modules and startup scripts) that I hope would make it very secure. Is there anyway I can test some malware on it? The virtual machine is versioned, so I can revert to a clean state easily.

Comment: "Is there anyway I can test some malware on it?" I have no idea what you are asking. What do you mean?

Comment: Ubuntu (and pretty much all other operating systems) ship with reasonably secure defaults. What kinds of modifications did you make, and what attacks are those modifications supposed to protect against?

Comment: @schroeder Sample malware. Downloading viruses. Exposing it to worms.

Comment: I'm still confused. Just infect it with malware?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to get sample malware?
According to the book Advanced Malware Analysis, there are a few public resource to get those like:

```
malshare.com
Open Malware (http://gtisc.gatech.edu/)
malwareblacklist.com
```

You can find out more in that book.